# importing a CSV file

Tags: r

I just started learning R which is my first programming language. I tried importing a CSV file from my system which is on my downloads in my computer using:

```
getwd()
setwd("/downloads")
statesInfo <- read.csv('stateData.csv')
```

But i keep getting the error message below.

> setwd("/downloads")
>   Error in setwd("/downloads") : cannot change working directory
>   statesInfo <- read.csv('stateData.csv')
>   Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In file(file, "rt") :
>     cannot open file 'stateData.csv': No such file or directory.

Could I be getting it wrong.

Comment: Does the downloads directory exist on your machine? Are you sure you're putting the righ slash? (depending on whether you're on windows or mac, different path conventions are used)

Comment: i think your folder is wrong maybe somethin like "~/downloads" would help. However if you set the working directory to downloads all your output will be written to it. So probably better just use the absolute or relative path to your file

Comment: What is your output from `getwd()`?

Answer (score 2):

R is unable to recognize the directory that you're referring to and that's why you get the first error.

The working directory remains unchanged and R can not find the file `stateData.csv` in the current working directory which results in the second error message.

For setting a working directory use the full path instead: `setwd("C:/Users/yourname/Downloads/")` - notice the forward slash instead of the back-slash.

However, If you're only importing files, you do not need to change your working directory every time. You can simply refer to files in other locations. If you're using windows - you will need to use `./` for sub-folders and `../` for folders that are one level up. For example. if your working directory is set to 'C:/Users/yourname/Desktop/R' and you want to read a file from the 'Downloads' folder, simply use the below code:

```
dat <- read.csv("../../Downloads/stateData.csv")
```

the first `../` takes you one level up to the 'Desktop' and the second `../` takes you to 'Users'. From there you are referring to 'Downloads' folder where the `stateData.csv` file is located.

**EDIT**

The above works for Windows isntallations, for Mac/others you would have to use the tilda notation: e.g. `~/Desktop`

Answer (score 0):

So, it should be like this.

```
setwd("c:/mydir")
```

Also.

```
MyData <- read.csv(file="c:/mydir/TheDataIWantToReadIn.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
```